# UIPickerView Default Value is Null

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I'm using a `UIPickerView`, and it has the first value chosen by default. When the user doesn't move the `UIPickerView` from this initial selection, however, the value selected comes back as `NSNull`. How can I make it so either:

1. The first value is recognized whether the user changes the selection or not.
2. The `UIPickerView` contains a blank value that I can check for in the first spot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
[_picker selectedRowInComponent:0]
```

`nil`  means no one move the picker (you can make the first item blank or sth like "--" )

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27058363/471840