# UIPickerView initializes with null (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview

I'm creating an app that uses UIPickerView.  When I run the app, if I don't manually move the picker, the default value is "null" (even though is SHOWS that a value is selected).

I've tried running `[picker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES]` within the `viewDidAppear` method, but the value for the picker is still "null".

Below is a screen shot of the picker as it is initialized, BEFORE being moved manually, but AFTER the method mentioned above has been run:

[image: Initialized]

And the output if you select "GO!" without manually moving the picker

[image: Output]

Any thoughts?  This is the same question as can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746104/uipickerview-default-value-is-null) thread, which has yet to have been answered.

Thanks much.

**EDIT:**

I use the following code to initialize the picker and obtain the value:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [self.pickerArray count];
}
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    self.valueOne = (NSNumber *)[self.pickerArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
-(NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [self.pickerArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Looking at it now, I think the simplest solution is to just set `self.valueOne` (name changed solely for this thread) to the desired value straight away.  So in my `viewDidLoad` method, I've included:

```
self.valueOne = @45;
```

This does the job, so I'll just leave it at that.  Simple enough work-around.  But please feel free to add to a different solution

Comment: Could you show the code you're using to get the selected value?

Comment: More code added.  Sorry for that.  In my interface I do include `<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>` and within my implementation file I have `self.picker.delegate = self;`

Comment: I'd say your workaround is ok. At least I used it myself a number of times. :-)