# Set a default value for UIPickerView in Swift?

Tags: swift, uipickerview

How do I set the starting row of the picker view in Swift?

I see [there is a similar question for Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777072/how-to-set-a-default-value-of-a-uipickerview), but I don't understand the code.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

This is the code I have used in one of my apps:

```
// Declare the outlet to the picker in your storyboard
@IBOutlet var myPicker: UIPickerView!

//...

override func viewDidLoad() {
//...
    myPicker.selectRow(row, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
}
```

Obviously, replace `row` and `0` with whatever values you want.

Comment: Hi, 
I tried your suggestion but it gave me an error.  Maybe because I have already called it?? in :

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate { 

And maybe that conflicts?  I tried also to put it further down together with the 

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
        return 3   

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
        switch component {
        etc...

Comment: Could you give me more details about the error you received?

Did you remember to connect the outlet to a UIPickerView in your storyboard?

Comment: Hey,  Thanks for following up, I was busy changing the pickerview font in another color and I had to change quite bit of the whole code to implement some code suggestions from @POB. I just finished it and implemented your code in the new  ViewController now.  It worked like a charm !!  I am not sure what was wrong with the old code.  THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: Question: If I set the row as above and want the picker to open on that specific row, then how do I do this in viewDidLoad() after I select the row?

Comment: Instance variables do not begin with a capital letter.

Comment: Just a tip - make sure you call this before constraints, as for me I got conflicting constraints for some reason if I put it after.

Answer (score 14):

```
@IBOutlet weak var mPicker: UIPickerView!
var items: [String] = ["NoName1","NoName2","NoName3"] // Set through another ViewController
var itemAtDefaultPosition: String?  //Set through another ViewController

//..
//..

var defaultRowIndex = find(items,itemAtDefaultPosition!)
if(defaultRowIndex == nil) { defaultRowIndex = 0 }
mPicker.selectRow(defaultRowIndex!, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
```

Comment: For swift 2.0:  var defaultRowIndex = items.indexOf(itemAtDefaultPosition!)

Answer (score 5):

**SWIFT 5**

The function "SetDefaultValue" will position the pickerView on the desired string by finding the item position in the pickerData which is used to populate the picker view. In this example it will be "item 2"

```
var pickerView = UIPickerView()
var pickerData = ["item 1","item 2","item 3","item 4","item 5"]
var defaultItem = "item 2"

func setDefaultValue(item: String, inComponent: Int){
 if let indexPosition = pickerData.firstIndex(of: item){
   pickerView.selectRow(indexPosition, inComponent: inComponent, animated: true)   
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put this line  `myPicker.selectRow(row, inComponent: 0, animated: true)`
in
override func viewDidAppear

Comment: In the accepted answer the same solution is mentioned, except it's placed in `viewDidLoad()`. Can you explain why you think it's better to do it in `viewDidAppear()`?

Comment: in my code when I put it in viewDidLoad() I did not take any result it seemed like the app cycle bypassed it  but when wrote it it in viewDidAppear() it worked well

Comment: viewDidLoad() is only called when the view is created, whereas viewWillAppear() is called every time the view will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Default value selected in pickerview in swift 3

If Your array like bellow

```
let pickerArray  = [
        ["displayValue":"--Select--" as AnyObject,"id":"" as AnyObject],
        ["displayValue":"Jame" as AnyObject,"id":"100" as AnyObject],
        ["displayValue":"Enamul" as AnyObject,"id":"201" as AnyObject]
    ]
```

Just add bellow line for default selected in pickerview

```
 pickerViewTextField.text  = pickerArray[0]["displayValue"] as! String
```