# The item appearing when I open my UIPickerView is not considered "selected"

Tags: swift, uipickerview

When I open my UIPickerView the item appearing is not considered selected in didSelectRow, I have to move up and down and reselect it

This is an extra step for the user if the item appearing is the item he/she actually wants to select

Is there a workaround that I can use to prevent this?

I've tried `pickerView.selectRow(selectedRow, inComponent: 0, animated: false)` which actually let me display the right item but whatever is displayed is not picked up by `pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)`

Here's how I build my picker:

```
customPickerView = UIPickerView()
customPickerView.delegate = self
textField.inputView = customPickerView
customPickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "whiteToBlack")
slwpDatesPickerData = dateArrayRange(inclusiveStartDate: Date(), inclusiveRange: 10)
customPickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a default Value of a UIPickerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777072/how-to-set-a-default-value-of-a-uipickerview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to force the selection by adding `pickerview.delegate?.pickerView?(pickerview, didSelectRow: 0, inComponent: 0)` after `pickerview.selectRow(selectedRow, inComponent: 0, animated: false)`